# Unable to use Admin card while deploying bna to network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Hi I have downloaded the Business network archive from the playground to my local storage. Now I am trying to install it to fabric from the command line. I used the below command.

```
composer network install --archiveFile  ~/Downloads/testing.bna --card ~/Downloads/admin.card
```

but I am getting error in command line that admin.card does not exist as shown below:

```
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Card not found: /home/user/Downloads/admin.card
```

though I have downloaded the card from playground and I can see it in download folder.

[image]

Can someone tell me why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have already inported the card (someone with Peer Admin authority, gets to install the business network) to do the `composer network install` (did you set the Development environment as shown here? -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

You will (in Step Four of that doc) run  a `createPeerAdminCard.sh` script to create / import a PeerAdmin card FILE,  which creates and imports the card [with the right Fabric authorities](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/blob/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/createPeerAdminCard.sh#L66) to the Composer wallet store.

Then (once that card is imported to the wallet store using `composer card import` - as shown in that script) - you would do the `composer network install` (using a Peer Admin card, ie one that's already imported) as follows:

composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile ~Downloads/testing.bna

Comment: Thank you Paul! I think it happened because I used ".card" instead of "@hlfv1"

Comment: can you please tell me if testing.bna is the right way. because it says : 
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Archive file ~Downloads/testing.bna does not exist.

Comment: correct - you used the wrong value to the parameter. On your question: it kind of depends 'who you're logged in as ' - try with the absolute path to the .bna file (not sure how you created testing.bna - so I can't tell if its a valid file)

Comment: I am loggedin as a user not root. I tried with absolute path. I used composer playground to create a new business network and after making changes to asset and participant in model.cto I downloaded it to local storage(testing.bna) from where I am using it. 
I can even see a docker container dev-peer0.org1.example.com.testing-0.0.2 which is not running right now. I guess it will once I install command will succeed
can you now tell me where I may got wrong.

Comment: I assume using absolute path to .bna didn't return 'file does not exist' error ? (You didn't confirm the latter actually worked). If you've got a 'dev-xx' container, it would suggest it was created. You still have to do the `composer network start` command sequence to instantiate it on the channel (unless you also mean to say you did this too).  See earlier doclink for syntax for `composer network start` command.